# sql query to avoid duplicate row based on value of the column

Tags: mysql

table name: pc_product

```
id_merchant      product_feed_name  
flipkart          moto 3G
flipkart          moto 3G
flipkart          moto black 3G
snapdeal          moto 3G
snapdeal          moto 3Generation
snapdeal          moto black 3G
jabong            moto 3G
jabong            moto 3Generation
jabong            moto black 3G
```

I want a result:

```
flipkart            moto 3G
snapdeal            moto 3G
jabong              moto 3G
```

If a product is found in flipkart next time it shouldn't retrieve me the same product from flipkart. It should search in other merchant's list

Comment: It isn't clear how you are resolving duplicates.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below :

```
select id_merchant, product_feed_name
from pc_product
where product_feed_name='moto 3G'
group by id_merchant
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the question is formed correctly but something along the lines of

```
select id_merchant, max(product_feed_name) as product_feed_name 
from pc_product group by id_merchant
```

should do the trick.
fell free to change max to min